# Have you coloured your hair?

Tags: meaning-in-context

My friend has recently changed the colour of her hair and it suits her. I would
say: "Have you coloured your hair?" it looks nice.  Is this correct?

Is it clear I am referring to a recent act of colouring and that I am not asking if she has ever coloured her hair?

Comment: When referring to hair, you'd usually ask if she *dyed* it, not *coloured* it.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski  - Not necessarily. _Dyed_ suggests (to me, at least) a dramatic, unsubtle colour change, while colouring could simply be an enhancement of her natural shade.

Comment: Yes. Dyed is slightly rude and could be taken as a criticism. _Have you changed your hair colour?_ is often heard.

Comment: This is interesting, I had no idea "dye" has a negative connotation, to me it just means changing your hair colour by way of hair dye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying "Have you coloured your hair? It look nice." makes it clear that you are talking about a recent event. After all, if it had been coloured a year ago and not since, the hair would not look particularly nice.

The question "have you coloured your hair?" is not specific about when, though it most commonly refers to a rcent event. Context is needed to clarify the time frame.

To be specific about the time you could ask "Have you coloured your hair recently?", or "Have you ever coloured your hair?"